# Spring Webflux: Write response body in WebFilter

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am trying to write a `WebFilter` which makes some checks on the http request. If the checks fail, I want to return http error 400 with an error message as the response body.

I have this code:

```
@Order(1)
@Component
public class CheckingFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        String errorMessage = doSomeChecks();
        if (errorMessage == null) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } else {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            DataBuffer responseBuffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(errorMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return response.writeWith(Mono.just(responseBuffer));
        }
    }
}
```

When the check fail, the return code is set correctly, but the response body is empty. How do I write the response body?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `Content-Type` header. Here is the updated working code:

```
@Order(1)
@Component
public class CheckingFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        String errorMessage = doSomeChecks();
        if (errorMessage == null) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } else {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            DataBuffer responseBuffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(errorMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return response.writeWith(Mono.just(responseBuffer));
        }
    }
}
```